# mail cannot be delivered in PHP even SMTP server is running and PHP mail() returns true

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to use PHP to send a simple mail. I have tried to use telnet to check whether Mercury is running, and it replys yes. Also mail() returns true, therefore my scripts should be okay, however mail still can not be sent, what may be the cause of this problem?

Here is my PHP code:

```
$subject = "Simple mail";
$message = "Here is a test mail";
$to = "me@gmail.com";
$from = "me@test.com";
$header = "From: ".$from;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))
   print "success<br>";
else
   print "fail<br>";
```

Below is my PHP.ini:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost  

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
sendmail_path = "C:\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

So if the mail server is running correctly, and the scripts are right, then the only problem causes mail cannot be delivered should be the mails have never arrived the server, then what can I do to find out where is the error and solve it?

I have followed the important notice to make some changes.

Comment: First thing would be to check the smtp servers logs...

Comment: T 20120725 161556 501017fa Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20120725 161557 501017fa 
T 20120725 161627 501017fa Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 31 sec. elapsed.
I just see this message, but cannot find the important 'Mail From' and 'Rcpt To' commands

Comment: And I dont know why, sometimes it even does not have any modification in the log file, so it seems like the mail has even not reached the server at all

Comment: 31 secs for an email ? Sounds like a timeout. Oh, and: sure you want to use that strange 'mailtodisk' thing you specify in your php configuration ?

Comment: it doesn't matter which way being used, I just want to send an email successfully, I have been working on this for two days, but still cannot find out the problem. If I want to use Mercury installed in XAMPP to send the email, how should I modify the php.ini?

Comment: Does your ISP allow outbound SMTP? Most ISP's require you to relay SMTP out through their SMTP servers to prevent spam from their networks.

Comment: em..This may be the causes, but how can I check whether my ISP allow it?

Answer (score 0):

In your XAMPP you are using "C:\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe" instead of a mail server. It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder, not sending them to internet.